# Python - Using spaces only not solving class methods 'IndentationError' on compilation?

Tags: python-3.x, class, visual-studio-code, indentation

Learning class construction, and of course I'm stuck with the 'IdentationError: unexpected indent' on the following code:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, name, balance, min_balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.min_balance = min_balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance - amount >= self.min_balance:
            self.balance -= amount
        else:
            print("Sorry, not enough funds!")

    def statement(self):
        print("Account Balance: £{}".format(self.balance)


class Current(Account):
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        super().__init__(name, balance, min_balance=-1000)
```

I believe I have exclusively used spaces for indents but I am still unable to get ahead of this one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Technically maybe not the original problem you were facing. Your line 17's call to print() is not closed off ; you need another ")" at the end of the line.

Comment: Yep you're right, missed it earlier. Thanks @zaTricky